# Dynamic Linq placeholders don't work properly

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I've got the following query:

```
query.Where("@0 != null && @1.ToString().Contains(@2)", 
            searchedColumnName, searchedColumnName, searchedValue);
```

And it doesn't work (There are multiple records that should be retreived).

For example, let `searchedColumnName == "MY_COLUMN"`, and `searchedValue == "8"`. When I debug into Dynamic Linq methods, the resulting `LambdaExpression` expression is:

```
{Param_0 => ((Convert("MY_COLUMN") != null) AndAlso "MY_COLUMN".ToString().Contains("8"))}
```

Now, If I don't use placeholders, like:

```
query.Where(searchedColumnName + " != null && " +
            searchedColumnName + ".ToString().Contains(\"" + searchedValue +"\")");
```

the `LambdaExpression` is:

```
{Param_0 => ((Param_0.MY_COLUMN != null) AndAlso Param_0.MY_COLUMN.ToString().Contains("8"))}
```

and it works.

I guess it means I use the placeholders incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with the way you write the placeholder.

Your column name "MY_COLUMN" is considered as the string, **not as a column**.

So I think, you can not use the placeholder for the column name here. You can use below code:

.Where(searchedColumnName+ " = @0", searchedValue);

For C#6
.Where($"{searchedColumnName} = @0", searchedValue);

Refer this link. It explains the dynamic INQ filter very well:

https://q-a-assistant.info/computer-internet-technology/dynamic-linq-filter-never-retrieves-correct-results-uwp-xaml/676258